# Android: RadioButton dynamically generated

Tags: android, radio-button

How it is possible to influence the distance between Buttons of a dynamically generated vertical-ordered RadioGroup ?

maksimilian

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,  you can set the margin of each radio button dynamically while adding them.

You just need to add 2 lines to your code

```
params.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
```

Full code is will be as shown below

```
String[] servers = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("ARRAY");
    Integer l = servers.length;
    final RadioGroup group = findViewById(R.id.your_radio_button);
    for(int i=1; i < l; i++){
        final RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
        rb.setId(View.generateViewId());
        rb.setText(servers[i]);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(10,10,10,10);  //this is the line you need to add
        rb.setLayoutParams(params); //this line you need to add
        group.addView(rb);
    }
    group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {.......}
```